# Porcentaje en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

hola amigos que tal tengo una duda para sacar el porcentaje en android es que vi como se hacia en android y se supone que es similar este es mi codigo en android: Donde se supone hago esto

suma2= a un total de una operacion anterior
ini = es el valor que introduje

y se supone que en java se saca el porcentaje asi

porcentaje= (numero/100)*cantidad; un ejemplo

alguien puede ayudarmem me salen numeros muy elevados

package com.example.danhermes.despensa;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class despensa extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
EditText etdisponible, etcompra, etcantidad, etarticulo, etinicio;
Button btncomprar, btnaceptar;
TextView tvporcentaje;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.despensa);
    etdisponible = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etdisponible));
    etcompra = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etcompra));
    etcantidad = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etcantidad));
    etarticulo = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etarticulo));
    etinicio = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etinicio));

    btncomprar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btncomprar));
    btnaceptar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btnaceptar));

    tvporcentaje = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvporcentaje));

    btncomprar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnaceptar.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnaceptar) {
        try {
            //tabla=Float.parseFloat(et_tabla.getText().toString());
            String inicio=etinicio.getText().toString();
            String articulo=etarticulo.getText().toString();
            String cantidad=etcantidad.getText().toString();

            int ini=Integer.parseInt(inicio);
            int art=Integer.parseInt(articulo);
            int cant=Integer.parseInt(cantidad);

            double suma=(ini-art*cant);
            String resultadosuma=String.valueOf(suma);
            etdisponible.setText(resultadosuma+ " Cantidad Restante");

            double suma2=(ini-suma);
            String resultadosuma2=String.valueOf(suma2);
            etcompra.setText(resultadosuma2+ " Total de Compras");


            double porcentaje=(suma2/100)*ini;
            String porciento=String.valueOf(porcentaje);
            tvporcentaje.setText(porciento);


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de escribir numeros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.btncomprar){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de escribir Compras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ya lo intente y sin embargo me sale demasiado amigo, por otra parte tu codigo me ayudo a reducir mucho el mio pero no resolvio mi pregunta

Comment: quieres el porcentaje de que? dame un ejemplo para entenderte mejor

Answer (score -1):

Para obtener el % de una cifra se debe usar `double` para las
cantidades, y `float` para obtener el porcentaje en si.

Ejemplo: el % de 20, de una cantidad maxima de 100, sería 20%,
si la cantidad maxima es 80, entonces el % sería 25.

```
EditText num,max;
TextView total;

double d1 = Double.parseDouble(num.getText().toString());
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(max.getText().toString());

float porciento = (float) ((d1/d2) *100);

String porcentaje = Float.toString(porciento);

total.setText(porcentaje);
```

En tu caso sería así:

```
double ini = Double.parseDouble(etinicio.getText().toString());
double art = Double.parseDouble(etarticulo.getText().toString());
double cant = Double.parseDouble(etcantidad.getText().toString());
double resta = ini-art*cant;

float porciento = (float) ((resta/ini) *100);

String porcentaje = Float.toString(porciento);

tvporcentaje.setText(porcentaje);
```

500 es el 100%, 175 el 35%, 325 el 65%

Comment: Ya lo intente y sin embargo me sale demasiado amigo, por otra parte tu codigo me ayudo a reducir mucho el mio pero no resolvio mi pregunta

Comment: si mira por ejemplo
tengo 3 edittext donde yo ingreso ciertos valores
en un edittext tengo Inicio en otro tengo articulo y en otro tengo cantidad

lo que yo quiero hacer es que de la multiplicacion del articulo por la cantidad pueda restarselo al numero de inicio y sacar el porcentaje de cuanto resta me resta

ejemplo

inicio 500
articulo 35
cantidad 5

se supone que 35 por 5 son 175
despues a 500 le resto 175 y quedan 325
a esos 325 quisiera sacarle su porcentaje